# Why does ::after content take up so much vertical space?

Tags: css

I'm trying to recreate a design I saw on a bootstrap blog without using bootstrap, which involves placing a `"` as my content using the `::after` selector. While it looks good on my page, and everything is placed correctly, the content is so large that it blocks elements below it, which is troublesome since those elements are sometimes buttons.

You can easily see the issue when I highlight the character in IE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXRA3.jpg.

I assume it's taking up so much vertical space because the font size is so large (200px). Is there a way to fix this? I understand that I could use a background image in place of my `::after` content, but would prefer to avoid that approach if possible.

```css
div::after {
  content: "”";
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  right: 17px;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 200px;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use that " in a span .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a `position: relative;` to your `div` element to position the `:after` correctly :

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div::after {
  content: "”";
  height: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  right: 17px;
  font-family: Georgia, serif;
  font-size: 200px;
  line-height: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<p>Test</p>
```

**Edit :** Adding `overflow: hidden;` on the div fix the bottom space.

Comment: yup, this did it